# How to determine details from a FormatException

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, exception

I have a C# asp.net web application which connects to a MySQL database. Intermittently with one user, I am getting a System.FormatException when trying to list the results from the database.

The exception occurrs when we call products.ToList() in the function below:

```
    private void ReloadCache()
    {
            var products = _context.Products.
                Include(p => p.Category).
                Include(p => p.Protocols).
                Include(p => p.LocalizedDetails.Select(pl => pl.Language)).
                Include(p => p.Costs.Select(pc => pc.Region.Currency));

            _productCache = products.ToList(); // exception thrown here
    }
```

In the stack trace, I can see the exception is actually thrown when trying to read a value from the database, and converting it to a decimal:

```
System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Cylon.QuoteEngine.Application.Web.BasePage' threw an exception. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseDecimal(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
   at System.Convert.ToDecimal(String value, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ToDecimal(Object value)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.GetDecimal(Int32 i)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetTypedValueDefault(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal)
   at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetValue(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal)
   at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.GetPropertyValueWithErrorHandling[TProperty](Int32 ordinal, String propertyName, String typeName)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )
   at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly[TEntity](Func`2 constructEntityDelegate, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )
   at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper)
   at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.RowNestedResultEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.ObjectQueryNestedEnumerator.TryReadToNextElement()
   at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.ObjectQueryNestedEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Cylon.QuoteEngine.Persistence.ProductRepository.ReloadCache()
```

I can catch the FormatException with a try catch block, but I do not have any more information on what string is failing to convert, or what table or column it is reading from. It merely states the issue occurred and I am none the wiser.

This application has been running for a couple years already, and only recently with one user has this issue started to intermittently occur. 
I have inspected the data in my DB, and ensured that the types match what is expected.

Is there a way to get information on the string, column, table or anything else that I can use to determine what is happening?

Comment: Have you run the SQL manually or profiled it to see what is being generated?

Comment: @WilliamXifaras Sorry I'm not sure I understand... Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: @ChrisJ The LINQ to SQL is converted to SQL and run on the database. If you profile the query, you can find out what the exact SQL query being run against the database is and can then reproduce the issue.

Comment: Is there anything in the `FormatException`'s `InnerException` property?

Comment: @wablab It is "Input string was not in a correct format." Not hugely useful in figuring out why it is incorrectly formatted.

Comment: @user1666620 Oh ok, I understand now. The problem is I am unable to reproduce this while debugging, or on my local machine. It only occurs for one user so far, so while I can get the exact query when I run it, no problems occur when I run it on the DB.

Comment: @ChrisJ you need to be looking at the same data as the user. Take a copy of the production database and load it on your local environment, log in as that user, and you ought to then be able to reproduce it. Set your breakpoints in the application, and narrow down the request to figure out which one is causing the error. You can modify the code to loop through the returned IENumerable, each element will be loaded separately and you will be able to figure out on which record the error occurs.

Comment: If the numeric columns are actually varchar in the DB, then perhaps there is whitespace between the number's sign (e.g. '-') and the value itself.  For example, "- 123.456" would fail to parse because of the space between the hyphen and the 1.

Comment: @wablab can't for the life of me think why somebody would store a numeric value as a varchar in the database. Sounds like a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @user1666620 I have a copy of the production DB and am logged in as the same user. While debugging I've copied the query and run it on the DB, and it loads no problem. This is only ocurring intermittently anyway, so its not happening everytime...

Comment: @user1666620, unfortunately, I see this happen pretty regularly.  Agreed that it's bad practice.

Comment: @wablab I've checked for white spaces, and am only storing numeric values as int or decimal as needed. As I said, it's been running fine for a couple years now and only happening intermittently. so I want to be able to catch the exception being thrown and get the information (where, what table or column, what value etc.) so the next time it occurs I'll be able to see what's happening.

Comment: @ChrisJ this can be a problem with linq, everything is so abstracted that it can be very hard to debug when things go bad. As I suggested earlier, change the method to use a foreach on each element of  your `products` variable, that way you will know which record is causing the error.

Comment: @user1666620 This is what I'm finding out! I'm used to developing C++ desktop apps, and can usually figure out most of that on my own. But with linq, asp.net and web aps in general, I'm still learning.

Comment: @ChrisJ, looks like there's some localization going on in your app?  Could there be a monetary value stored in the DB that uses a currency symbol or currency separator that is incompatible with the language/region under which the process runs for the particular user who is experiencing the problems?  This might cause ParseDecimal to fail.